# How to call wp_localize_script() after the script?

Tags: wp-register-script, wp-localize-script

I am trying to use the WordPress path URL in my js script file. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221630/wordpress-path-url-in-js-script-file) that I need to use `wp_localize_script`. But, I according to Codex's documentation

> wp_localize_script() MUST be called after the script has been
>   registered using wp_register_script() or wp_enqueue_script()

How can I do that?

This is my function

```
if(!function_exists('pt_scripts')):
    function pt_scripts () {
        wp_register_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri(), null, '1.3.1', 'all');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style');
        wp_register_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/script.js', array('jquery'), '1.3.0', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts' );
    }
 endif;

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','pt_scripts');
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what's not clear? You've registered your script, `'scripts'` on the 3rd and 5th line of your function respectively, so you just need to use `wp_localize_script()` after those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to call `wp_licalize_script` after registering the script, because you need handle of that script... And of course you can't localize something that doesn't exist...

Here's some example:

```
if ( !function_exists('pt_scripts') ):
    function pt_scripts () {
        wp_register_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri(), null, '1.3.1', 'all' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );
        wp_register_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/script.js', array('jquery'), '1.3.0', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts' );

        wp_localize_script( 'scripts', 'ScriptsData', array(
            'some_data_1' => 'data1',
            ...
        ) );  // 'ScriptsData' is name of object that you can access in your JS
    }
endif;

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pt_scripts' );
```

PS. '`scripts`' is not the best name for script handle - it's pretty easy to get some conflicts with such names.